# findOne returns Object instead of Document

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections

[image: Console Object Document]

Leads and Customers are both collections. Why does `Leads.findOne()` return an Object? It should return a Document as `Customers.findOne()` does.

I am using Meteor 1.2.1.

Comment: It depends on definition of your types as it's not possible to specify without posting some code.

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity, or is the type difference causing an issue?

Comment: All my `findOne()`s return *Objects*. I don't remember ever seeing a *Document*. That's the type of the web page itself!

Answer (score 1):

It's because collection `Customers` has been transformed via the `_transform` method whilst collection `Leads` hasn't.

See the `transform` parameter of `Mongo.Collection` in the [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection).

It's very likely you are using the [dburles:collection-helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers) package which adds the `transform` automatically.